# Let $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\Sigma^{*}$ be a collection of all subsets $E\subseteq S$ for which there exist sets $F, G\in \Sigma$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reviewing measure theory for probability theory, and I came upon this question.

Let $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\Sigma^{*}$ be a collection of all subsets $E\subseteq S$ for which there exist sets $F, G\in \Sigma$ such that $F\subseteq E \subseteq G$ and $\mu(G - F) = 0$. Prove that $\Sigma^{*}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I've done $S\in \Sigma^{*}$ by setting $E = G = F = S$, but I'm stuck with how to prove closedness under complements and countable unions.

Comment: and... what have you tried?

Comment: Seems you still don't understand [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|127.8346).

Comment: The question is well-posted, except that the OP should also state that "Let $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space..." at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E\in\Sigma^{\ast}$. Choose $F,G\in\Sigma$ such that $F\subseteq E\subseteq G$
and $\mu(G\setminus F)=0$. Observe that $G^{c},F^{c}\in\Sigma$,
$G^{c}\subseteq E^{c}\subseteq F^{c}$ and $F^{c}\setminus G^{c}=G\setminus F$,
so $\mu(F^{c}\setminus G^{c})=\mu(G\setminus F)=0$. Hence, $E^{c}\in\Sigma^{\ast}$.

Let $(E_{n})$ be a sequence of sets in $\Sigma^{\ast}$. For each
$n$, choose $F_{n},G_{n}\in\Sigma$ such that $F_{n}\subseteq E_{n}\subseteq G_{n}$
and $\mu(G_{n}\setminus F_{n})=0$. Define $E=\cup_{n}E_{n}$, $F=\cup_{n}F_{n}$,
and $G=\cup_{n}G_{n}$. Note that $F,G\in\Sigma$ and $F\subseteq E\subseteq G$.
Moreover $G\setminus F\subseteq\cup_{n}(G_{n}\setminus F_{n})$, so
$\mu(G\setminus F)\leq\sum_{n}\mu(G_{n}\setminus F_{n})=0$. It follows
that $E\in\Sigma^{\ast}$.

This shows that $\Sigma^{\ast}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.